# Preventing Nix from upgrading git to git-full

Tags: package-management, upgrade, nix, nixpkgs

I'm using [Nix](http://nixos.org/nix/) on Ubuntu to have more modern versions of some packages, one of them being git. When I'm run `nix-env -u`, this is what happens:

```
% nix-env -u --dry-run '*'
(dry run; not doing anything)
upgrading `git-1.8.5.4' to `git-1.9.0-full'
```

This is not what I want - I prefer the plain version `git-1.9.0` over the `-full` version. I know I can manually upgrade to the plain version with `nix-env -i git-1.9.0`, but is there a way to make `nix-env -u` to do what I want?

Answer (score 4):

Before I go and answer this one, I'd like to explain how naming of packages works in Nix.

The name you are referring to is derivation name, that is not unique (multiple packages compiled in different ways can be `git-1.9.0`).

If you want to reference a package in unique way, attribute set name is the way.

To print out attribute set name while querying (note `-P`:

```
nix-env -qaP | grep git
```

To update a package by unique name:

```
nix-env -uA git
```

In your case, this is a result of the fact that both packages are called `git-version`. Nix resolves which one is picked up by priority. To lower priority for the one currrent one, set:

```
nix-env --set-flag priority 10 git
nix-env -u
```

Comment: Based on the IRC discussion: `--set-flag priority` does not actually help here, and it might make sense change the naming convention of the package variants in Nixpkgs: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/1756

Comment: See https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/1756#issuecomment-37316142, this has been fixed.